# Compare a list of strings with each other optimally

Tags: c#, .net

I want to compare a list of strings with each other using Damerau to Levenshtein Distance

Currently i have:

```
char lastchar = (char)('z'+1);

        SimilarStrings similarStrings = new SimilarStrings();

        List<String> listString = new List<string>();

        listString.Add("Rammstein");
        listString.Add("Ramstein");
        listString.Add("Rammsten");

        listString.Add("Metallica");
        listString.Add("Metalica");
        listString.Add("Metaica");

        for (int i = 0; i < listString.Count(); i++)
        {
            for(int n = 0; n < listString.Count(); n++)
            {
                String str1 = String.Copy(listString[i]);
                String str2 = String.Copy(listString[n]);
                Console.Write(str1); Console.Write(" to "); Console.Write(str2 + "\n");
                int DADistance = SimilarStrings.damerauLevenshteinDistance(str1, str2, (int)lastchar);
                Console.WriteLine(DADistance);
            }
        }
```

This works fine basicly, the only problem is every comparison is done twice. That means e.g. "Rammstein" is compared to "Metallica" and then "Metallica" is compared to "Rammstein" again. Half the comparison would be enough. But how do I do this in a good way? I can only think of some complicated ways.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing each element with each other element in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031771/comparing-each-element-with-each-other-element-in-a-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard way is to start the inner loop from the outer loop index plus one.

```
for (int i = 0; i < listString.Count(); i++)
    for (int n = i + 1; n < listString.Count(); n++)
```

That's assuming you don't want to compare each string to itself - if you do, remove the `+ 1`.

Here's an example of the logic. If your list was: `a b c d`, you would want to compare `a` to:

```
a <> b
a <> c
a <> d
```

For `b`, you don't need to compare `b` to `a`, because you already compared `a` to everything. So you can start from `c`:

```
b <> c
b <> d
```

And for `c`, you already compared `a` and `b` to everything, so you can start from `d`:

```
c <> d
```

So each element only needs to be compared to elements *after* it in the list - which is what is expressed by the nested loops above.

Answer (score 1):

This should prevent duplicate comparisons

```
    for (int i = 0; i < listString.Count(); i++)
    {
        for(int n = i + 1; n < listString.Count(); n++)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```